# Missing properties on System.Web.Http.HttpError

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Unless I'm going mad, `HttpError` should have the following properties:

- `Message`
- `ModelState`
- `MessageDetail`
- `ExceptionMessage`
- `ExceptionType`
- `StackTrace`
- `InnerException`

I can see them in the source code [here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/1b78397f32fc#src/System.Web.Http/HttpError.cs) and they are all public.

However, after installing the latest packages from NuGet the only public property on `HttpError` is `Message`.

Am I missing something really obvious here?

Comment: Could you confirm the version number number of the assemblies you are using. There is also a HttpError in System.Web.HttpError are your using statements clear?

Comment: Yes. Navigating to definition of HttpError displays the correct class - `System.Web.Http.HttpError` in `Assembly System.Web.Http.dll, v4.0.0.0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking is the [master](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/1b78397f32fc) branch which has the latest. If you look at the [v2-rtm](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/75b5e7ea58d2) branch, you will see that `System.Web.Http.HttpError` class only has `Message` property for the RTW release of the ASP.NET Web API:

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/75b5e7ea58d2#src/System.Web.Http/HttpError.cs